# Details Panel icon in wix installer

Tags: c#, wix, installation

how to add a icon for details panel in wix . I found that ARPPRODUCTICON can be used to change icon in add/remove program but most applications have different icons set .

```
<Property Id='ARPPRODUCTICON'>appicon.ico</Property>
<Icon Id="appicon.ico" SourceFile="..\..\..\Images\abcd.ico" />
```

Comment: What _details panel_ is? Do you mean logo in standard `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` bootstrapper ([see here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_branding.html)) or top logo in standalone MSI installation wizard ([see here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html))?

Comment: details panel is the one that comes in bottom of window when a program is clicked in add/remove program in control panel

Comment: _"but most applications have different icons set"_ different where? Application icon, installer icon and add/remove programs icon?

Comment: check this link [Wix icon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ju4GG6LiwcV2pzOXk4UTA2anM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, do you want different icons for the list and the _details_ pane? Did you try to include different images in your .ico file (according to size)?

Comment: you mean single .ico file containing two images..?

Comment: Yes. .ico files usually contain multiple images (16x16, 24x24, 32x32, etc). Control Panel will pick right one according to view mode (list, small icons, details, tiles) and location (program list, details pane)

Comment: It's not about size i want two different images.

Comment: Please reread that comment. Put different images and you'll have different images but remember CP will pick them according to size it needs, you can't have different images with same size (for example in tile view) because CP _knows_ only one icon.